# Função fecth: O cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente

Tags: javascript, java, front-end, typescript, restful

Estou tentando simular uma aplicação que estou executando num servidor Glassfish local. A IDE que estou usando é: Intellij.
Construi um método que consome um serviço de uma API vindo de um endereço:

```
http://localhost:8080/<BACKEND>/rest/home/listar
```

Estou tentando consumir através do endereço:

```
http://localhost:3002/
```

Este é o erro gerado no browser:

> Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same
>   Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em
>   http://localhost:8080//rest/home/listar.
>   (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está
>   presente). NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

O Algoritmo que usei na minha aplicação frontend foi:

### HomeController.ts

```
importaLista() {

        function isOk(res : any) {
            if (res.ok) return res;
            else throw new Error(res.statusText);
        }

        fetch('http://localhost:8080/corujito.com-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/home/listar')
            .then(res => isOk(res))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (dados:any[]) => {
                    dados.map(dado => new Ensaio(dado))
                    .forEach(ensaio => this._ensaios.adiciona(ensaio))

                }
            ).catch(
                err => console.log(err.message)
            );
    }
```

### EnsaioDao.ts

```
import { Ensaio } from "../models/Ensaio";

export class EnsaioDao {

    private _listas: Ensaio[] = [];

    adiciona(negociacao: Ensaio): void {
        this._listas.push(negociacao);
    }

    paraArray(): Ensaio[] {
        return ([] as Ensaio[]).concat(this._listas);
    }

    paraTexto(): void {
        console.log('Impressão');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this._listas));
    }

}
```

### app.ts

```
import { HomeController } from "./controllers/HomeController";

const homeController = new HomeController();

homeController.importaLista();
console.log(homeController.getList());
```

Comment: @wmsouza Não é uma publicação duplicada. Apesar de usar AJAX, o modo que estou usando é pela função fetch(). O código acima demostra. Mas agradeço o seu apoio.

Comment: localhost:8080 é diferente de localhost:8080, logo não tem como resolver no front-end, isso já foi muito debatido no site, CORs se resolve no back-end e o teu back-end é o "servidor Glassfish", logo tem que resolver na sua we-baplicação em `http://localhost:8080//rest/home/listar`